# Linux API to get info about filesystem

Tags: linux, api

I am looking for a linux api that returns me information about root filesystem.

I can use command stat -f / to get information about root filesystem. Is there any API that returns exactly same information as returned by "stat -f" command ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Next time when you need to know API than does the same thing like a shell command you can use `strace`. Like this: `strace stat -f /` and see what calls do command. On my system it calls `statfs64`.

Answer (score 1):

[statvfs](http://linux.die.net/man/2/statvfs), link goes to a manpage.

Comment: can that be used as a regular non-root user?

Comment: The link in this answers is now dead. A currently usable documentation link lives here: https://linux.die.net/man/2/statvfs